# Alt JS "_alt2.default is not a constructor" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this error when application is loaded. Compiling is ok without any error.

> Uncaught TypeError: _alt2.default is not a constructor

in this file `alt.js`

```
import Alt from 'alt';
const alt = new Alt();
export default alt;
```

in React and Alt JS application with WebPack.

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.4",
    "alt-container": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.9.1",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "marked": "^0.3.5",
    "react": "~0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.1.11",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -wdc --progress",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  }
}
```

**Webpack configuration**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: [
        './src/app.js'
    ],

    output: {
        path: '../webroot/js/build',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: function (filename) {
                if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return /\.js$/.test(filename) !== -1;
                }
            },
            loaders: ['babel-loader']
        }]
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
    }

};
```

What is wrong?

**Edit #1**

I've used `externals` in Webpack config:

`externals: /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/,`

and error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined

Comment: I thin you nned to have an `externals` definition in your webpack config?. One that excludes precompiled stuff like `alt` and `react`. The discussion here seems to be relevant: https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/259

Comment: What's in your `.babelrc` file? It doesn't look like you have any Babel presets installed.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?